# How can I expand git URL to its canonical form in magit?

Tags: magit

In magit, if I call `git-link` in a buffer that is visiting a file being
version controlled, I get a github link.

Is there a way to get the canonical form of that link directly from emacs, without having to go to github and press `y` to get the canonical form for that link?

Comment: The help for `git-link` states `The URL will be added to the kill ring`, so after calling `git-link` you should be able to paste the URL anywhere within Emacs. If you don't want `git-link` to automatically open the browser, you can set `git-link-open-in-browser` to `nil`.

Comment: `git-link` uses the branch name instead of the commit-hash to generate a link, e.g. https://github.com/MyUser/myProject/blob/myBranch/README.md. I actually wondering if something like `git-link-canonical` already exists, ideally this function would return https://github.com/MyUser/myProject/blob/d1f0971c83624186e776b37af7ddc8e1a5399583/README.md

Comment: `git-link` can generate links that use the commit hash if `git-link-use-commit` is set to non-nil. By running `(setf git-link-use-commit t)`, `git-link` will generate the links using the commit hash instead of the branch name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-link` can generate links that use the commit hash if `git-link-use-commit` is set to non-`nil`. By running `(setf git-link-use-commit t)`, `git-link` will generate the links using the commit hash instead of the branch name.